# LinkedHashSet не удаляет повторяющиеся элементы

Tags: java, arraylist

Проблема в следующем: необходимо удалить повторяющиеся элементы ArrayList'а. Для этого использую следующий код:

```
private List<NameCode> removeAllRepeated(List<NameCode> list) {
  Set<NameCode> hs = new LinkedHashSet<NameCode>(list);
  list.clear();
  list.addAll(hs);
  return list;
}
```

Но удаление не происходит. Класс NameCode:

```
public class NameCode {
  private String name;
  private Integer code;

  public NameCode(Integer code, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Integer getCode() {
     return code;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.code == ((NameCode) obj).getCode();
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return getCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас неправильно реализованы методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` в классе `NameCode`.

Comment: А как тогда лучше реализовать?(

Comment: Посмотрите в моём ответе ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Измените методы `equals()` и `hashCode()` в классе `NameCode` на такие (сгенерировано IntelliJ)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    NameCode nameCode = (NameCode) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, nameCode.name) &&
            Objects.equals(code, nameCode.code);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, code);
}
```

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое)

Comment: Пожалуйста. На будущее, всегда проверяйте, что объекты, которые вы кладёте в `Set` или используете как `key` в `Map`, имеют правильную реализацию этих двух методов.